# Regular Expression sc.next("[0-9/]+") vs sc.next()?

Tags: regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read numbers from a text file and I am not sure what is the difference between `sc.next("[0-9/]+")` and `sc.next()`?

Comment: `"[0-9/]+"` a character class that gets either a single digit or a forward slash, quantified 1 or more times, surrounded in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

if you specify a regex in the next method, It gets you the specified input only, where as next() method returns you an entire line of input and returns a String.